# 'NoneType' object is not callable when calling a function written in C# from Python

Tags: c#, python, dll, interface

I'm a newbie to Python and C#.  I'm trying to make a dll in C# with two methods implemented as **interface**, and call them in python file after registering in COM.

```
namespace Sample
{
    public interface interf
    {
        bool printHello(string name);

        void printWorld();

    }

    public class A : interf
    {

        public bool printHello(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            return true;
        }


        public void printWorld()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling these functions in python as:

```
import win32com.client

dllCall = win32com.client.Dispatch("Sample.A")
hello = dllCall.printHello("Hello")
dllCall.printWorld()
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to execute the python file.

```
Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\sampleTest.py", line 23, in <module>
World!
    dllCall.printWorld()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What is that I'm missing?

Comment: Nice first question! Most first questions are pretty bad...

Comment: It's just a hunch but I think you are not allowed to call methods which have the type "void" as it is referred to as "NoneType". You may need to give each method a real type in order to make it work.

Comment: But if I add an argument like void printWorld(string name) and call it from python as dllCall.printWorld("World") the above code works fine.  Then what is the problem if I call it without argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working.
If I call `printWorld` without brackets `()`.

```
dllCall.printWorld
```